# Encountering psycopg.OperationalError: connection is bad: Temporary failure in name resolution, when attempting to run migrations using GitHub Actions

Tags: python, django, postgresql, github-actions, django-migrations

Currently attempting to implement backend CI for a project using Django for the server and PostgreSQL for the database. I'm automating this using GitHub Actions to occur whenever a pull request is done, but when it tries to attempt migrations, it gives me the error mentioned in the title. I've temporarily changed it to run on a push to the branch so I don't have to make a new pull request every time I want to test it.

This is the relevant bits from the .yml file:

```
name: Backend CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test-branch
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: server

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_HOST: db
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_DB: github-actions
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
      ...

      - name: Run Migrations
        env:
          API_SECRET_KEY: secret-key
          POSTGRES_HOST: db
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
          POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
        run: |
          source .venv/bin/activate
          python manage.py migrate

      ...
```

What I expected to happen was for migrations to run smoothly, but it instead throws me the error from the title.

What I've tried so far:

- Specifying hostname for the db
- Providing the expected hostname and password for the server to connect to

Someone I asked told me to check if I'm running Django in the container and I think I am? I was under the assumption that Django was running in the same virtual environment as the database would be.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely what seemed to work was unspecifying a hostname, I took out `POSTGRES_HOST: db` from the services block and changed db to localhost in the host name under the migrations bit.